# Using std:fstream how to deny access (read and write) to the file

Tags: c++

How can I deny access to a file I open with fstream? I want to unable  access to the file while I'm reading/writing to it with fstream?

Comment: I need to read from the file and change lines according to the content. I want to avoid changes in the file while I'm reading and writing to it (have latest data & don't override)
I implented it using fstream, do I need to change the whole code to using handles and buffers (readfile) or can I get a Handle from fstream? I had trouble with readfile and writefile because I need to read line by line and write so . (with fstream I used getline function.
fstream fs(path)
while (! file.eof() )
   getline (fs,line);
do something...
fs.write(str, str.size());
fs.clear();
fs.close();

Comment: Do you want to protect your file from another instance of your program, or from a different program? For the first, an easy solution is to use lock files/directories - most programs do it this way. For the second, I've never seen it happening - if you really need it, see my answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You cannot do it with the standard fstream, you'll have to use platform specific functions.

On Windows, you can use [CreateFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx) or [LockFileEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365203.aspx). On Linux, there is [flock()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock), [lockf()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/lockf), and [fcntl()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl) (as the previous commenter said).

If you are using MSVC, you can pass a third parameter to fstream's constructor. See the documentation for [Visual Studio 6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243822(VS.60).aspx) or [newer versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8et8s826.aspx). Of course it won't work with other compilers and platforms.

Why do you want to lock others out anyway? There might be a better solution...

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435091/sh-none-is-not-a-member-of-stdbasic-filebuf-elem-traits/4435481#4435481) provides more information on using `fstream`

Answer (score 9):

*Expanding on the comment by Casebash:*

To open a file in windows so that other processes cannot write to it use

```
file.rdbuf()->open(path, std::ios_base::app, _SH_DENYWR);
```

_SH_DENYRW will deny both read and write access

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this in native C++, as it would be highly platform dependent. On Linux/UNIX, you can do this with [`flock`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock) or [`fcntl`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl). I'm not really sure how to do it on Windows.

On windows, it looks like you have to pass some flags to [`CreatFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858.aspx) or use [`LockFileEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365203.aspx) (which allows byte range locking).

Note that, all of these methods work on the underlying OS file descriptors/handles, not with `fstream`s. You will either need to use the Posix or Windows API to read/write from the file, or wrap the file descriptor/handle in an `fstream`. This is platform dependent again. I'm sure there is a way to do it, but I don't remember it off the top of my head.

Comment: I know this is 10 years old, but how can be locking a file more platform-dependent then any other file operations that use also platform-specific syscalls?