# File Type For SaveFiles c++

Tags: c++, windows, fstream, file-type

Using fstream, what file type would you recommend that I can read and write to for save files? I'm attempting to make a program where the user enters a username and a password and it'll output it to a file. I'd like a filetype that isn't very easy for the user to edit. (so not a .txt or .ini)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not use a .txt and [**lock it**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853805/locking-files-using-c-on-windows)?

Comment: Any file is easy to edit if you write bare text into it.

Comment: Sandra I'm not using unix

Comment: If it's sensitive information I'd write to a binary file, preferably encrypted. However you shouldn't store passwords, not even encrypted. You should store their hash.

Comment: @CowNation file extensions have no inherent meaning. You can write your stuff to a `.txt` or a `.sav` or even a `.mp3` and it won't make a lick of a difference.

Comment: thanks mate. I'm not sure how to store the hash of the information of the files or how to encrypt it tho.

Comment: @Zinki how are different file types not different?

Comment: @CowNation Different file extensions are arbitrary, they don't change what the file contains. They are just part of the name and have meaning only by convention. You can select anything you like.

Comment: @CowNation the only thing file extensions are for is so windows can try to deduce a default program to open it with in case of double click. So a .txt file might be set to open with notepad++ and a `.mp3` might open with media player. But that's just a user setting, the file extension is meaningless by itself. If you write your text to `.mp3` and your music to `.txt` everything will work just fine as long as you tell windows to open mp3s with notepad and txt with media player.

Comment: That is not unix

Comment: Stop downvoting just because I'm not as knowledgeable about c++ as you.. jesus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fstream doesn't really have a sense of a "file format" outside of being in text mode vs pure binary mode (there are some nuances with newlines for example). You would typically use some sort of intermediate library to generate or directly write XML files, JSON files, INI files, etc. SQLite is a popular library/format to store database tables in a file. Mozilla Firefox uses it for their bookmarks and history for example.

What you're talking about is security through obscurity. By using using some sort of encoding, perhaps ultimately binary so it wouldn't even be printable at all without a hex editor, it would obscure things a bit. If you used encryption it wouldn't be readable until decrypted, but you could always reverse engineer the program to determine the encryption/decryption keys and algorithms.

The most secure option is to not store the password at all, but a hash of the password. This means that even with reverse engineering the program, you wouldn't be able to directly extract the stored password. Instead, whenever the user attempted to enter a password, it would compare use the same hashing algorithm and compare the results.

This doesn't always work though, because sometimes you are storing the password to submit to a 3rd party, in which case you do have to ultimately recover the stored password into plaintext for transmitting to the 3rd party.

I hope this gives you some ideas!

Comment: Thanks.. this was very thorough and helped!