# sh_none is not a member of 'std::basic_filebuf<_Elem,_Traits>'

Tags: c++, visual-c++, iostream, file-sharing

I am trying to use the Microsoft Specific [filebuf::sh_none](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243822%28VS.60%29.aspx) variable to open an `fstream` in an exclusive mode (another Microsoft specific function). I am getting the above error. I am importing `<fstream>`. How can I fix this error?

**UPDATE**: I found this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/2bea83b3-f07a-4868-8f86-81fc0bf5adc4), where it was suggested that I try _SH_DENYNO instead. The code compiles, I am testing it now. This doesn't make any sense to me, as this isn't documented in the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version of Visual C++ are you using?

The Visual C++ 6 documentation you linked to is the pre-standard version of iostreams, from `#include <fstream.h>`.  It's no longer available, and even in Visual C++ 6.0 was only there for backward compatibility.

Also, `_SH_DENYNO` is the opposite of exclusive mode.  You want `_SH_DENYRW` to get the same behavior as `sh_none`.  Here is the new documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44cs32f9.aspx, which ends up directing you to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f30b0db.aspx for details on the third parameter.