# Prevent opening file in "rw" and "r" at the same time

Tags: linux, windows, macos, c++11

I'm writing class to r/w files from OS file system or from my own archives format in my game engine. How can I make impossible to open file by `std::fopen()` or `std::fstream` in modes `"rw"` and `"r"`. I have written some code to test that on Linux. Here's it:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    fstream in("file.txt", ios::in | ios::out);

    if(!in.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Plik nie może być otwarty w trybie rw" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "Plik otwarty w trybie rw" << endl;
    in << ".test.";
    cout << "Wpisano tekst" << endl;

    while(1){}

    return 0;
}

/* Drugi plik */
/* The second src code */


#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    fstream in("file.txt", ios::in);

    if(!in.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Plik nie może być otwarty w trybie r" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "Plik otwarty w trybie r" << endl;
    cout << in << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I've executed the `./rw` program and some instances of `./r`, the `./rw` has gone into endless loop and the instances of `./r` have terminated with `0` code.

Sorry for my English. :)

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/839897/19746

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using std:fstream how to deny access (read and write) to the file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839856/using-stdfstream-how-to-deny-access-read-and-write-to-the-file)

Answer (score 1):

You should "lock" the file using `lockf()`: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/lockf.3.html

Comment: But this isn't cross platform.

Comment: Well you mentioned Linux in the question.  What platforms do you need to support?

Comment: I put also `windows` and `osx` in tags. I would support how much platforms as is possible. ;)

Comment: There is no standardized file locking.  You have to either explicitly put in code for each platform you're targeting, or use a third-party library such as Boost.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Boost doesn't have file locking as contemplated here.  It has something called "file lock" or similar but that is different from "locking a file."

Comment: Qt then, or one of the others.

Comment: I have installed Boost lib-dev on my Ubuntu then I'll use the `boost::interprocess::file_lock` (btw. terrible naming, better is Java naming convention IMHO).