# Ofstream file overwritten whenever it's opened

Tags: c++, overwrite, ofstream

So I have to make a bank program for an assignment, and my professor wants a log file of every "operation"(He was really vague about that, I decided to log inputs and outputs). The issue I'm having though is that every time I call a new function, I have to reopen the file and it overwrites what was previously there. As far as I can tell, using .open repeatedly will cause whatever function I'm in to ignore the previous output.
  I tried declaring a global ofstream hoping that it would change, but the issue persists either way. Flushing and/or closing didn't seem to help,but it's entirely possible I misused them or the syntax was wrong. The code below is the main function, read_accts function, and menu function. If I terminate the program before calling the read_accts function, the log file will have "How many accounts are there?" But if I allow the program to call the other two functions, then the log file only has the output of the menu file. I apologize for the long post, but I'm at a loss as to what's going wrong.

```
int main()
{
    ofstream log;
    log.open("Log.txt");
    int MAX_NUM = 100;
    BankAccount account[MAX_NUM];
    int num_accts = 0;
    char selection = 'Z';
    cout << "How many accounts are there?" << endl;
    log << "How many accounts are there?" << endl;
    cin >> MAX_NUM;
    read_accts(account, MAX_NUM, num_accts);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "There are " << num_accts << " accounts" << endl;
    log << "There are " << num_accts << " accounts" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    print_accts(account, MAX_NUM);
    cout << endl;
    `

    while (selection != 'Q' && selection != 'q')
    {

        menu();
        cin >> selection;
        log << selection;
        switch (selection)
        {
            case 'W':
                case 'w':
                withdrawal(account, num_accts);
                break;
            case 'D':
                case 'd':
                deposit(account, num_accts);
                break;
            case 'N':
                case 'n':
                new_acct(account, num_accts);
                break;
            case 'B':
                case 'b':
                balance(account, num_accts);
                break;
            case 'I':
                case 'i':
                account_info(account, num_accts);
                break;
            case 'C':
                case 'c':
                close_acct(account, num_accts);
                break;
            case 'Q':
                case 'q':
                print_accts(account, num_accts);
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Invalid selection" << endl;
                log << "Invalid selection" << endl;

        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    print_accts(account, MAX_NUM);
    cout << "Goodbye" << endl;
    log.close();
    return 0;
}

int read_accts(BankAccount account[], int MAX_NUM, int &num_accts)
{
    ofstream log;
    log.open("log.txt", std::ofstream::app);
    string f;
    string l;
    int social;
    int acct;
    string type;
    double bal;
    int i = 0;
    ifstream readfile;
    readfile.open("bankdatain.txt");
    if (!readfile)
    {
        cout << "Can't open input file." << endl;
        log << "Can't open input file." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    while (readfile >> f >> l >> social >> acct >> type >> bal)
    {
        account[i].setfname(f);
        account[i].setlname(l);
        account[i].setssnum(social);
        account[i].setacctnum(acct);
        account[i].settype(type);
        account[i].setbalance(bal);
        i++;
        num_accts++;
    }

    return num_accts;
}

void menu()
{
    ofstream log;
    log.open("Log.txt");
    cout << "W - Withdrawal" << endl;
    log << "W - Withdrawal" << endl;
    cout << "D - Deposit" << endl;
    log << "D - Deposit" << endl;
    cout << "N - New account" << endl;
    log << "N - New account" << endl;
    cout << "B - Balance" << endl;
    log << "B - Balance" << endl;
    cout << "I - Account Info" << endl;
    log << "I - Account Info" << endl;
    cout << "C - Close Account" << endl;
    log << "C - Close Account" << endl;
    cout << "Q - Quit" << endl;
    log << "Q - Quit" << endl;
    cout << "Please make your selection: " << endl;
    log << "Please make your  selection: " << endl;
}
```

Comment: You could just open the file in append mode.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, by default, ofstream will open file in std::fstream::out mode, if will erase the existed file or create new file.

Change it to std::fstream::app
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/

Edited:
Seem like you use two ostream to just one file. It can't deny access [Using std:fstream how to deny access (read and write) to the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839856/using-stdfstream-how-to-deny-access-read-and-write-to-the-file)

Pass the ostream to called function

```
int read_accts(BankAccount account[],int MAX_NUM,int &num_accts, ostream& log)
{
log.open("log.txt",std::ofstream::app); // remove this line since you already open it in main()
```

while call it in main

```
read_accts(account,MAX_NUM,num_accts, log);
```

Comment: Fstream doesn't make a difference, is it possible that using "file.open" in main() and then using it again in another function causes the issue? I guess I'm looking for a way to keep the file open across every function, if that's possible.

Comment: @CharlieMonnone Updated!

Comment: Passing log as a parameter doesn't appear to work; as far as I can tell once I call the read_accts function ofstream stops working.

Comment: @CharlieMonnone you should remove the .open in read_accts since you already open the file in main, then you pass its references, it no need to open it again.

Comment: It's working now, removing   log.open("log.txt",std::ofstream::app);  did the trick. Thank you!.

Comment: Opening a file that is already open is considered failure to open [and `open` "Calls setstate(failbit) on failure."](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open) `failbit` needs to be cleared before continuing. Better to just not reopen the file.

Answer (score 0):

I think your only problem is That you must add this before you write into file.

`log.seekp(0, std::ios_base::end);`

this will set the file pointer to the end of file and continue to write from there.

Your file is already open in `int main ()` it will be better if you pass the variable `log` into the function `int read_accts(BankAccount account[], int MAX_NUM, int &num_accts)`
and make it `int read_accts(BankAccount account[], int MAX_NUM, int &num_accts, ofstream log );`

and make its definition

```
int read_accts(BankAccount account[], int MAX_NUM, int &num_accts, ofstream log )
{
    string f;
    string l;
    int social;
    int acct;
    string type;
    double bal;
    int i = 0;
    ifstream readfile;
    readfile.open("bankdatain.txt");
    if (!readfile)
    {
        cout << "Can't open input file." << endl;
        log << "Can't open input file." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    while (readfile >> f >> l >> social >> acct >> type >> bal)
    {
        account[i].setfname(f);
        account[i].setlname(l);
        account[i].setssnum(social);
        account[i].setacctnum(acct);
        account[i].settype(type);
        account[i].setbalance(bal);
        i++;
        num_accts++;
    }

    return num_accts;
}
```

**PS** syntax of `seekp()` is

```
  ostream& seekp (streampos pos);
  ostream& seekp (streamoff off, ios_base::seekdir way);
```

refer [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/seekp/)

**PS** its equivalent for `ifstream` is `seekg ( 0, std::ios_base::end )`